# csvデータを一次元配列にしたい

Tags: python, csv

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

というデータが一列だけのcsvファイルがあります。

```
import csv

with open("~.csv") as fp:
    lst = list(csv.reader(fp))
print(lst)
```

出力するとこのように二次元配列になってしまいます。

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['5']]
```

`[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`となるようにしたいです。

Comment: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`となるようにしたいとのことですが、通常のCSVファイルのように、各行にカンマ区切りのデータがあった場合は、どう出力することを想定していますか？例えば、１行目が`1`ではなく、`1,a,b,c`だったら、どのような出力になることを想定していますか？

Comment: エラーチェックなしで良いのであれば `with open('~.csv') as fp: lst = [int(r[0]) for r in csv.reader(fp)]` でしょうかね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 方法1

目的のファイルが「複数のデータが1行にコンマで区切られて書かれているファイル」ということではなく「1行に必ず1つのみデータがあるファイル」ということであれば、CSV として読み込むのではなくファイルから各行読み込めば良いです。

```
with open("test.csv") as fp:
    data = fp.read().splitlines()
print(data)
```

参考

- [How to read a file line-by-line into a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3277503/5989200) -- Stack Overflow

### 方法2

CSV を二次元リストとして読み込んだ後、一次元リストに flatten することでも解決できそうです。Python で二次元リストを一次元リストに flatten するためにはたとえばリスト内包表記が使えます。

```
with open("test.csv") as fp:
    csvList = list(csv.reader(fp))
flatList = [item for subList in csvList for item in subList]
print(flatList)
```

参考

- [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/5989200) -- Stack Overflow
- [Python Tips：多重リストをフラットにしたい](https://www.lifewithpython.com/2014/01/python-flatten-nested-lists.html) -- Life with Python

Comment: できました！ありがとうございました！